# Returning the length of a selected item from an anonymous function

Tags: jquery

I have written an anonymous function to help me get the length of the selected item after when there is `change` event.

I have this code

```
var ac = {
    x: $(".choose_salutation").change(function () {
        var the_selected_len = $(".choose_salutation option:selected").val().length;
        return the_selected_len;
    })
};
alert(ac.x);
alert(Object.keys(ac.x).length);

/**
var b = 300 - ac.x;
var elem = $(".chars");
$("#le_message_compose").limiter(b, elem);
*/
```

Why can't i get the length when i call `ac.x`?.

**Edit:The HTML**

```
<select class="form-control choose_salutation" name="anrede"><option selected value="keine_anrede">No Salutation</option><option value="Bon Jour">Bon Jour</option><option value="Good Morning">Good Morning</option><option value="Good Morning">Good Afternoon</option><option value="Good Evening">Good Evening</option><option value="How are you,">How are you</option></select>
```

Comment: can you post your HTML?

Comment: edit it in your question

Comment: try using : var the_selected_len = $( ".choose_salutation option:selected" ).text().length;

Comment: How is `var the_selected_len = $( ".choose_salutation option:selected" ).text().length;` different from `var the_selected_len = $( ".choose_salutation option:selected" ).val().length;` when getting the length?.

Comment: May be this is an `xy` problem. If you explain why you want to do this, there will be a better solution. Maybe what you want to do is to call another function with the length value from the change call back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access it outside, just have a variable outside and set it's value from the anonymous function.

```
var ac;
$(".choose_salutation").change(function () {
    ac = $(".choose_salutation option:selected").val().length;
})
alert(ac); // undefined if change didn't occur, length value after change occurs.
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your jQuery as:

```
    var ac = {
x: $( ".choose_salutation" ).change(function() {
var the_selected_len = $( ".choose_salutation option:selected" ).text().length;
alert(the_selected_len );

return the_selected_len;
})
};
function pop()
{
alert(ac.x.val().length);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="pop()" value="show the result again!"/>
```

Your code won't work because alert is not inside the `change()` event!

So when the value changes the length will be returned but alert won't get called!

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

You can also write `var the_selected_len = $( ".choose_salutation option:selected" ).val().length;`

You can access the returned value outside of the function also! but you won't be seeing `alert()` on value value change.

I think that's pretty obvious if you write `alert()` outside of `change()` how are you supposed to see the `alert()` on value change!

Comment: Essentially,i would want to access the returned value outside the anonymous function not inside of it.

Comment: You then need to add alert outside also and inside change(), you will then need to modify your code more, your current code won't work in that case!

Comment: OMG,the last point.I quite never realized that.IMHO,if that was possible it would have worked wonders.

Comment: but it solves what you have mentioned in your question